# How do I display in my firebase database a list formatted in php webpage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I display in my Firebase database a formatted list in a PHP webpage using JavaScript?

I am trying to make a real-time web based chatting program.

I tried to display a formatted list but was unable to resolve this

I tried to display a Firebase database in PHP webpage by using XAMPP hosting but I was unable to solve it.

```html
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.18.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- =-------------------------include firebase database------------------- -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.18.0/firebase-database.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDqGtTYx6nMoRFBsJpwA6c1e_T7Y1RTuN8",
    authDomain: "simple-chatbox-676f6.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://simple-chatbox-676f6.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "simple-chatbox-676f6",
    storageBucket: "simple-chatbox-676f6.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "660420445050",
    appId: "1:660420445050:web:fd497421dc939274e70cc3"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  
  var myName = prompt("Enter your Name");

  function sendMessage(){
      // get message
      var message = document.getElementById("messaage").value;
      //save in database
      firebase.database().ref("messages").push().set({
        "sender": myName,
        "message": message
      });

      //prevent form from submitting
      return false;

      //listen for incoming messages
      firebase.database().ref("messages").on("child_added", function(snapshot){
        var html = "";
        html += "<li>";
          html += snapshot.val().sender + ": " + snapshot.val().message;
        html += "</li>";

        document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += html;
      });
      
  }
</script>


<!-- create aform to send message -->
<form onsubmit="return sendMessage();">
  <input placeholder="Enter message" id="messaage" autocomplete="off">
  
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<!-- create a list -->
<ul id="messages"></ul>
```

Comment: I am unable to understand exactly what it is you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is not the optimal language to make live chats since it would need to keep refreshing the page over and over again to print new messages (or messages log).

For this you could use PHP for back-end yes and work like a bridge with your firebase DB.

Yet, try and use Javascript fetch to keep making requests to the PHP file.

Explanation:

When the php file is called it will query the firebase DB and return the data in JSON structure and print it, like this it will return the JSON object to the fetch request as a reply.
This object can then be worked on with Javascript to render updates on the user page.

You need to understand that PHP runs on the server side while the rendered page is running on the client side.

To fetch information from a PHP file you can use the code below:

```
fetch('http://example.com/file.php') // URL of the file
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

The output of the PHP file is what your going to see on the browser console.